# How to work with stripe in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I have read and tried most of the blogs and tutorials regarding implementation of stripe in laravel 5.2 but none of them work out or none of them had proper explanation. Can somebody please provide me some simple to understand tutorial link. or can guide in simple language.
I'm new to laravel

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe/episodes/1 - Easy, in fact after watching this vid you'll be able to reference Stripe's documentation and easily work with it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think that watching this video from Jeffrey Way at Laracasts.com will give you a basic understanding of how to use Stripe inside a Laravel project.

The video is recorded using Laravel 5.3 but not much is different - https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe/episodes/1

Without watching the free video though, you can use `composer require stripe/stripe-php` to include the PHP library (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)

And then basically follow the instructions here and in the documentation - https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/php